# Spring security and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot

I have a question. Why spring security works only with spring boot?
I have the following configuration:

AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer

```
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    }
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            filter.setForceEncoding(true);
            http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
            ...
    }
```

I tried this just adding spring security dependencies, such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't work, but when I added

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

it started working. Why spring security works only with spring boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring security also works without spring boot. Use below dependencies it will work.

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.ver}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have this error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0;

Answer (score 0):

Spring security does not have any dependency with spring boot. Its a one of the module of spring which is use to handle security related functionality.

There are different ways to implementing spring security

1. By maven :- By updating pom.xml with following configration

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. By Gradle :- By adding following configuration build.gradle

   ```
   compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:$springSecurityVersion"

       compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion"

       compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:$springSecurityVersion"

       compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:$springSecurityVersion"

       compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:$springSecurityVersion"

       compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:$springSecurityVersion"
   ```
3. By Adding spring security jar file in project build path.